# Why did final -ie become so popular during early Modern English?

Tags: orthography, early-modern-english

A hallmark of Early Modern English is that it exhibits a lot of variance between the use of final -y and -ie.  In the 16th century -ie is even found in Old English words, eg stonie.  And Mulcaster in his Elementarie of 1582 effectively recommends the dominant use of -ie when he relegates final -y only to "sharp and loud" final vowels (eg, deny but prettie).  Why did -ie become so widely used in the 16th century?  Are there phonological reasons to select -ie over -y?  Is it due to contemporary French practices?  I assume it's a complex mix of causes - if so, is there a study into the "rise and fall" of -ie?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I notice a difference in stress (and in modern phonetic quality) between your two example words.

Comment: Possibly related discussion: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3135/origin-of-the-y-or-ie-diminutive-suffix-to-denote-intimacy-tenderness-e

Answer (score 1):

Phonetically they are identical nowadays, but they probably were pronounced differently in the past. I know that, at one time, in French the pronunciation of -ie was different than -i, and still is in poetry (the -ie indicating the feminine form of a word).  The ending -y is rarely ever found in French.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this statement? (Aside from the French pronunciation, which is a completely different language).

Comment: Completely different language, @PeterShor ? I guess you're referring to Modern French and Modern English. But Middle English was highly influenced by French in those days, wasn't it?

Comment: @Tim: Early Middle English may have been heavily influenced by French, but by the 16th century (which the OP is asking about), it was a completely different language.

Answer (score 1):

[According to *The Guardian*](http://www.theguardian.com/guardian-observer-style-guide-y), the -y and -ie suffixes have different origins in English:

> **y or ie?** As a general rule: -y is an English suffix, whose function is
>   to create an adjective (usually from a noun, eg creamy); -ie was
>   originally a Scottish suffix, whose function is to add the meaning of
>   "diminutive" (usually from a noun, eg beastie).
>
> So in most cases, where there is dispute over whether a noun takes a
>   -y or an -ie ending, the correct answer is -ie: she's a girly girl, but she's no helpless girlie. Think also scrunchie, beanie, nightie,
>   meanie ... There are exceptions (a hippy, an indie band), but where
>   specific examples are not given, use -ie for nouns and -y for
>   adjectives.

Questia has a link to an article excerpt by Kenneth Shields titled "[On the Origin of the English Diminutive Suffix -Y, -Ie](https://www.questia.com/read/1G1-92803251/on-the-origin-of-the-english-diminutive-suffix-y)", but the complete article is only available to subscribers.